# Distinct values count by Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have some values in GenericRecord, I need to count this distinct values by Kafka stream. Its must be something like this {"Distinct values count":123}. Please, help me. I`m new in Kafka Streams

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
SteamsBuilder topology = new StreamsBuilder();

KTable<Integer, HashMap<String, Long>> aggregate = topology.stream("input")
  .groupBy((k, v) -> 0 /*map all records to same, arbitrary key*/)
  .aggregate(() -> new HashMap<String, Long>(),
             (k, v, a) -> {
                Long count = a.get(v.get("state"));
                if (count == null) {
                    count = 0L;
                }
                a.put(v.get("state"), ++count);
                return a;
             });
```

(I omitted the `Serdes` in this case (`Consumed` in `stream()`, `Serialized` in `groupBy()`, `Materialized` in `aggregate()`), you'll need to provide those yourself.)

The resulting `KTable` will be a table of distinct state values to their respective counts.

Comment: Maybe my question was incorrect. I have GenericRecord, in this record I have some value, for example, {"state":1234}. I need to calculate, how many values have different "state". Little example: {"state": 1234}, {"state":1235}, {"state":1234}. Result will be {"Distinct values":2}, because there are two same values "1234"

Comment: Yes, in this case I have different keys and count of this keys, but if I need only one key, like a "Count of different keys" and value - count of this different keys. In your example: {"key1": count1}, {"key2": count2} ... What I need its one key with count of different values: {"One key": distinct values count}

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand. Maybe try explaining again? You can email me in Russian dminkovsky gmail if easier, but maybe update your question here with a clearer example.

Comment: Постараюсь обьяснить. В GenericRecord у меня есть некоторое поле "state", в нем попадаются разные значения, например, state = "1234", state= "1235" и так дале. Мне нужно сделать один ключ, например, "Количество уникальных значений" и как значение мне нужно посчитать количество етих разных значений. Например, у меня есть 4 значения: "1234","1235", "1234", "1236", то результат должен быть следующий: {"Количество уникальных значений": 3}. Потому что значение "1234" повторяется 2 раза.

Comment: Cool, I think I understand. I updated my answer. I suggested email because SO is English-only. So your comment above might be redacted. Maybe edit your question with the example from your comment? Vote up/accept my answer if you like it.

Comment: Oh, Thank you. Maybe you know how translate this code to Scala?

Comment: You’re welcome. I don’t know Scala. Only English, Russian, and Java :)