# Distinct Count of Events in a Time Window in Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a JSON string payload in a Kafka topic with fields `name`, `updatedTime`. I need to count the distinct names that would have arrived as different records, in a time window that is based on `updatedTime`. I have built a `TimeStampExtractor` for this already.
According to [KIP-655](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-655%3A+Windowed+Distinct+Operation+for+Kafka+Streams+API), the distinct count over a TimeWindow doesn't yet exist in the KafkaStreams DSL. I am wondering if there is way this can be accomplished using KafkaStreams.

> TimeWindow: 1 min

Source: These are separate records, coming in order one after each.

> {"max",1694535527}
>
> {"john", 1694535528}
>
> {"doe", 1694539696}
>
> {"stacy", 1694542526}

Output Topic: Counts as separate records:

> 2
>
> 1
>
> 1

Note: Tried the approach in the below link, but no luck since there is no TimeWindow that is being used: [Distinct values count by Kafka Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500452/distinct-values-count-by-kafka-streams)

---

### Update

I have implemented a custom DedupTransformer with the Transformer<> interface and forwarded all the de-duplicated `name`s in a given time window to a different stream (state store purges the windows that were > WindowDuration+GracePeriod). But counting these unique words may not reveal the actual counts in the above window and the aggregator is giving out ever-increasing counts instead of count for the window.

Should I use a stateful aggregation with KTable and TTL based KeyValueStore? But I see that it is not possible to do windowing and then apply TTLs on KeyValueStores, so not really sure how to get the true counts in a window.

Comment: As I encounter more or less same issue.
Can you please share your topology code?